# JSONexception in never thrown in the corresponding

Tags: java, android

Hi in the app that I build, it show me this error, in the `(JSONException e)`, What i may be?

> exception 'org.json.JSONexception' in never thrown in the corresponding

```
public void fetchData(final DataCallback callback) {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                        try {
                            callback.onSuccess(response);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                });

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

Comment: It means in your try catch there is no possibilty for that execption to occur. You don't need try catch for that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means in your try catch there is no possibilty for that execption to occur. You don't need try catch for that line

```
 public void fetchData(final DataCallback callback) {
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        callback.onSuccess(response);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```